# xlsread error - Undefined function 'biffread' for input arguments of type 'char'

Tags: matlab, xlsread

For one of my Matlab routines, I receive the following error message when reading an xls file with Matlab 2012b:

> Undefined function 'biffread' for input arguments of type 'char'. Error in xlsread (line 71). biffvector = biffread(filename);

The relevant line of code reads as follows:

```
[a,b] = xlsread('sheet.xls','sheetName')
```

When I modify the code as follows:

```
[a,b,c] = xlsread('sheet.xls','sheetName')
```

I receive another error message:

> Error using xlsread. Too many output arguments.

The puzzling part is that exactly the same lines of code work fine in another Matlab code of mine (apparently the problem is not related to the xls-file).

Can anyone explain this to me and how I can possibly solve this problem?

Comment: Have you overloaded `xlsread` somewhere? What is the output of `which xlsread`? What is the full error message and stack trace?

Comment: Overloading dos not seem to be the problem. To see the the full error message I amended the code as follows: `try catch
err = lasterror
disp(err)
disp(err.message)
disp(err.stack)
disp(err.identifier)
end` Then the full error message comes out as follows: _Error using <ahref="matlab:helpUtils.errorDocCallback(''xlsread'')" style="font-weight:bold">xlsread</a> Too many output arguments.'_  By theway, how to use `which xlsread` as you suggest above?

Comment: I checked once more and it seem that built-in xlsread was indeed overloaded by mistake. Thanks for pointing it out, I hope this way I will solve it!